# How to open file in existing Atom process from console?

Tags: bash, console, atom

If I have an instance of [Atom](https://atom.io/) open with some files already loaded, how can I open an additional file from the command line?

When I simply run:

```
atom filename.txt
```

It opens another instance of Atom (now two separate windows). How can I add the file as a new tab to the existing window?

Even better, what I would really like to do is Add Project Folder from the directory I'm currently in on the terminal console.

Comment: Try to run `atom filename.txt --profile-startup false`. Funny, but my atom is opening all files within same instance by default. What release is yours? Mine is Atom: 1.18.0/Electron: 1.3.15/Chrome  : 52.0.2743.82/Node    : 6.5.0

Comment: @Redbob please post that as an answer it works were I live :-)

Comment: I'm not sure that @George. Here at work, atom had same behavior and this parameter does not do the opposite if settled false. I think it's a misconfiguration at Jeff settings..

Comment: Jeff, rename `~/.atom` folder or delete it, restart Atom and try it again. Let's see if works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As revealed by `atom --help`, you can use the `-a`/`--add` flag to open a file or folder in the last used window.

**Example:**

```
atom -a <filename>
```

Comment: how to make this the default, aliasing it?

Comment: That depends on your shell and should be posted as a separate question